# Laravel 4 Call filter in controller with parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would ilke to know if there is a way in Laravel 4 to pass parameters to filter from controller. I've seen many solutions for Laravel 3 but it seems this is working differently in L4. There is no 'filter' method. It is only beforeFilter. I tried passing params with 'action:param' method but no success :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter as a string after your filter name. Use `:` to separate method name and parameter.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('filterSomething:param');
}
```

If you have many parameters, you can use `,` to separate your parameters.

```
$this->beforeFilter('filterSomething:param1,param2');
```

And then define your filter logic in `app/filters.php`. Don't forget to add parameter in your filter method for passed parameters.

```
Route::filter('filterSomething', function($route, $request, $param1, $param2)
{
    // Do something with your params.
});
```